# Show/hide data in <tr> based on enddate from entity

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

```
window.setInterval(function()
    {

        var expiryDate = $('.houdini').attr('data-enddate');

        var current = new Date();
        var expiry = new expiryDate;

        if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime())
        {
            $('.houdini').hide();
        }

        else if (current.getTime() < expiry.getTime())
        {
            $('.houdini').show();
        }

    });
```

the .houdini is a tr in my html. The tr is in a loop. It cycles through my Appointment Entity and prints a tr for each appointment.
Now i want to hide an appointment (later its going to be deleted) if its overdue and fade it out and "scroll" to the other appointments which are in the future.
But what this does is dont show the tr at all because of the classname.

Anyone's got a solution for this?

Btw I'm using Symfony with twig templating.

This is HTML

```
 <tbody>
        {% for appointment in appointments %}
            <tr class="houdini" data-endDate="{{appointment.endDate|date('Y-m-d H:i')}}">
                <td>{{appointment.startDate|date('H:i')}}</td>
                <td>{{appointment.client.companyname}}</td>
                <td>{% for employee in appointment.employees %}
                        {{employee.firstname}}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}</td>
                <td>{{appointment.description}}</td><br>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: send your html too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of could will be useful for you, let me know if you stuck in any error...

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    var houdiniElements = $('.houdini');
    for(var i =0; i < houdiniElements.length; i++) {
        var expiryDate = $(houdiniElements[i]).data('enddate'); // Here probably if you are using some different date format than you need to parse it accordingly...

        var current = new Date();
        var expiry = new Date(expiryDate);

        if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()){
            $(houdiniElements[i]).hide();
        } else if (current.getTime() < expiry.getTime()){
            $(houdiniElements[i]).show();
        }
    }
},1000); //1000 miliseconds = 1second
```

Here it would be nice if you have date in Y-m-dTH:M:S Format then you can easily convert date string to date object in javascript as shown below

```
var correctStart = '2012-11-10T13:10:13';
var date = new Date(correctStart);
```

OR

```
var start = '10/11/2012 13:10:13';    
var date = new Date(start);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the result from the data isnt a Date its just a string. You could save the Date.getTime() in the data and convert it to an intager instead of saving the Date.